# different node version conflicts while npm install

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, homebrew, nvm

I got this issue everytime I want to do `npx create-react-app my_app`

```sh
yarn add v1.15.2
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
error eslint@6.2.1: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. 
Expected version "^8.10.0 || ^10.13.0 || >=11.10.1". Got "8.3.0"
```

But when I do check my versions with nvm and bash here's what I got

```sh
$ node -v
v8.16.1
```

```sh
$ npm -v
6.4.1
```

```sh
$ nvm ls
nvm ls
->      v8.16.1
        v9.10.1
        v12.0.0
         system
default -> node (-> v12.0.0)
node -> stable (-> v12.0.0) (default)
stable -> 12.0 (-> v12.0.0) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/dubnium (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.16.1
lts/dubnium -> v10.16.3 (-> N/A)
```

I really don't get why it says while doing the `npx` command that I got node 8.3.0 and that version appears nowhere

**It may be because I've installed node with brew some times ago and it may conflict with nvm settings?**

---

It works when I issue `npm install -g create-react-app` and `create-react-app my-app` separately as it's what facebook recommends for old node version

```sh
$ npm install -g create-react-app
+ create-react-app@3.1.1
added 91 packages from 45 contributors in 4.491s

$ create-react-app trainin
yarn add v1.15.2
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.13.0" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@^5.0.0".
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/parser@1.13.0" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@^5.0.0".
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 7 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ react-dom@16.9.0
├─ react-scripts@3.1.1
└─ react@16.9.0
info All dependencies
├─ eslint-config-react-app@5.0.1
├─ react-dev-utils@9.0.3
├─ react-dom@16.9.0
├─ react-error-overlay@6.0.1
├─ react-scripts@3.1.1
├─ react@16.9.0
└─ scheduler@0.15.0
✨  Done in 15.45s.
```

Comment: Fix your nodejs version with nvm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better uninstall the version installed by brew, and setup the default version compatible with npx required.

Comment: Brew says that node is required by yarn, is it normal? Says I might try --ignore-dependencies but I don't want to break anything :/

Comment: Of course, yarn is nodejs's package manager.
I mean you should use one tool to manage your nodejs, brew or nvm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n?activeTab=readme) package which allow you to switch between multiple node versions